# OpenLayers 3: Refresh single Layer Source

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to refresh a single WMS layer source. Goal is to use a parameterized SLD with different thresholds. Points are drawn with different size and colour depending on these values.

```
var source = new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Global/wms',
                params: {
                    LAYERS: 'cities',
                    VERSION: '1.3.0',
                    CQL_FILTER: "ISO_A2 IN ('DE', 'FR', 'BE', 'PT', 'CZ', 'NL', 'ES', 'AT', 'CH', 'HU', 'PL', 'SE', 'NO', 'DK', 'IT', 'GB', 'IE')",
                    STYLES: 'ring_dynamic',
                    ENV: 'LOW_MAX:' + low_max + ';MED_MAX:' + med_max
                }
            })
```

After setting low_max and med_max parameters the layer should be reload to make the changes visible.

I've tried the following two statements but none of them worked.

```
source.changed();

source.dispatchEvent('change');
```

Using OpenLayers 3.6 and 3.6.

€dit:
I use a jQueryUI-Slider to trigger the reload:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
              range: true,
              min: 0,
              max: 5000000,
              values: [ 500000, 2000000 ],
              slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#grenzen" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                low_max = ui.values[0];
                med_max = ui.values[1];
                source.changed();
                source.dispatchEvent('change');
              }
            });
            $( "#range_limits" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
              " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
          });
```

This code is placed below the previously shown code.

Comment: show the code where these parameters are set.

Comment: Added code snippet to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use updateParams on the source http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#updateParams

Comment: Thanks! That worked. After calling this function only the required layer was refreshed.

Comment: Yeah the old docs got removed, try this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_TileWMS-TileWMS.html#updateParams

Comment: And for the last doc, version 3 webpage: https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html#updateParams

Answer (score 1):

I use openlayers v4.6.5 and I solved this problem like that

```
layerChanged(layer){
    layer.getSource().clear();
    layer.getSource().refresh();
}
```